# Dictionary doesn't return value for key that is present

Tags: powershell-2.0

I built a dictionary that I am trying to use in a script I'm building, but when I try to use the key to access a value from it, I am getting no response.

```
 $dictionary = [System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string,int[]]]::new() 
 foreach($obj in $Object){
        $formattedName = $obj.'Format'
        if(-not$($dictionary.ContainsKey($formattedName))){
            $Total= [int32]::Parse($obj.'Total')
            $charCount = $formattedName.length
            $intArray = @($Total,$charCount)
            $dictionary.Add($formattedName,$intArray)
        }
    }
```

When I check the dictionary I do get a filled object as expected:

```
Key         Value
A1          {1,2}
A2          {1,2}
A3456       {3,5}
```

But, when I try to access this dictionary by keys to get the corresponding values, I get no response from the console:

```
$dictionary[A1] 
$dictionary["A1"]
$dictionary["$($dictionary.keys[0])"]
```

returns: *nothing* instead of {1,2}

Trying to figure out where I am misunderstanding... When I check the member of $dictionary I get

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Int32[], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by including an output type for the function that was returning the dictionary

```
[OutputType([System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string,int[]]])]
```

I think the object the function I was calling to build the dictionary was returning an custom object instead of a generic dictionary.